# Depending on result display 40 separate images in a flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#

I have a datagrid that i fill with certain values and i then check are these values within limits. There will be x40 columns. I colour the cell green/red for pass/fail

```
public void colourTableCell(int rowIndex, double lowLimit, double highLimit)
{
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.White;

        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width = 60;
            DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[i];

            if (cell.Value is double)
            {
                double value = (double)cell.Value;

                if ((value < lowLimit) || (value > highLimit))
                {
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    failStatus[i] = true;
                }
                else
                    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                    cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I write the results to a text file

```
for (int index = 1; index < dataTable.Columns.Count; index++)
{
    sw.Write((failStatus[index]) ? "FAIL; " : "PASS; ");
}
```

what I want to do after the write is to display red images or green images in a 5x8 structure in a flowLayoutPanel for each indexes. So the image represents the index which will either be a pass/green or fail/red.

Comment: Not completely related to your question but: do you know that `cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;` is executed every time (`if ((value < lowLimit) || (value > highLimit))` being `true` or being `false`)? You have to add always curly brackets with `if`/`else` unless they consist in just one line (`cell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;` is inside the `else`).

Comment: It's unclear...do you have actual images you want to display?...or are you asking how to **build** some kind of image representing the 5x8 structure?

Comment: There are 40 columns each with 6 rows in the datagrid, if any of the rows pass/fail their limits i colour the cell, but what i want to do after that is to give an overall result of each column being either green/red depending of the result of any of their rows. The panel will be using two images, red circle, green circle displayed in columns of 8 by 5 rows each.